# cannot set property title of null

Tags: javascript

this code in line 130 keeps sending me error i don't know why

```js
 document.getElementById("btnEventDetails").title = EventID;
            document.getElementById("HFURl").value = imgFull.src;
            document.getElementById("HFEventID").value = imgFull.title;
```

but the first object  i assigned the same value in the top works fine

```js
var imgFull = document.getElementById("imgFull");
            var dl = document.getElementById("<%=rpImages.ClientID%>");
            var imgs = dl.getElementsByTagName("img");
            var Imagebtn = lnk;
            var EventID = Imagebtn.title;
            imgFull.title = Imagebtn.title
```

it assigns to the image control perfectly but it keeps getting error when assigning on a button

Comment: Can you please show the code from the middle?

Comment: do you have an element with id "btnEventDetails" in your html?

Comment: it depends on the fact that there are no elements with the ID **btnEventDetails** and the query via document.getElementById("btnEventDetails") returns null...

Comment: You keep mentioning an error, what is it exactly? In general error text is supposed to give you a good idea of what's wrong, so telling us what it actually says would be helpful.